# Flask code running individually but when containerized with docker, the page isn't reachable

Tags: docker, tensorflow, flask

I have a deep learning model,I deployed it using flask and it works perfectly when I send a post request via postman, I containerized the application in a docker, the docker seems to build and run fine but the host is always unreachable.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

I tried changing the port numbers etc
EXPOSE 5000 and I ran the docker using docker run -p 5000:5000 "name".
Nothing seems to be working.

This is the docker file-

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN pip3 install opencv-contrib-python-headless
COPY ./flask_code.py /deploy/
COPY ./requirements.txt /deploy/
COPY ./ResNet50_model_weights.h5 /deploy/
WORKDIR /deploy/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "flask_code.py", "production"]
```

This is my flask_code.py

```
from io import BytesIO
import pickle
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import model_from_json
import os
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import base64

model = None
app = Flask(__name__)

def readb64(base64_string):
    sbuf = BytesIO()
    sbuf.write(base64.b64decode(base64_string))
    pimg = Image.open(sbuf)
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pimg), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

def load_model_flask():
    global model
    # model variable refers to the global variable
    model = load_model("ResNet50_model_weights.h5") 


@app.route('/')
def home_endpoint():
    return 'Hello World!'


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def get_prediction():
    # Works only for a single sample
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()  # Get data posted as a json
        print(data['string'][:5])
        gray = readb64(data['string'])
        print(gray.shape)
        gray = cv2.resize(gray, (300,300), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        print("after", gray.shape)

        gray = np.expand_dims(gray, axis=0)
        print(gray.shape)
        pred = model.predict(gray)
        #print(pred)
        #data = np.array(data)[np.newaxis, :]  # converts shape from (4,) to (1, 4)
        #prediction = model.predict(data)  # runs globally loaded model on the data
        print("The class of this garbage is:")
        index = np.argmax(pred[0],axis = 0)

    return str(index+1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_model_flask()  # load model at the beginning once only
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',debug = False, threaded = False)
```

Flask_code.py is working fine when I run it individually.

I expect to get a "hello world" message when I go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/
instead it says "Connection was reset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.run(host='127.0.0.1',debug = False, threaded = False)
```

You are binding your app with localhost of the container so that is why it's not reachable from the host.

Change this too

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug = False, threaded = False)
```

So then it will reachable from host.

Comment: Hey! I did find a solution, let me just check if this works too. host = '0.0.0.0' basically means we are listening on all interfaces right?

Comment: Yes, localhost is only accessible on container localhost

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I didn't google enough.
I found the exact solution explained in a detailed manner here.
https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/